# Robots.txt Adds Unwanted Border to Menu

Tags: jekyll

Since adding a sitemap to my site with jekyll's sitemap plugin, `robots.txt` is showing an unwanted border in my menu list. Is there a way of removing/hiding the border?

[image]

Jekyll

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    {% for page in site.pages %} {% if page.layout == "home" or page.url contains ".xml" %} {% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    <ul class="actions">
        <li class="content"><a href="#contact" id="contact-btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="actions vertical">
    <li><a href="#" class="button special fit">Subscribe to Newsletter</a></li>
</ul>
```

HTML Output

```
<!-- Menu -->
<nav id="menu">
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="/about/">about</a></li>

        <li><a href="/archive.html">archive</a></li>

        <li><a href="/robots.txt"></a></li>

        <ul class="actions">
            <li class="content"><a href="#contact" id="contact-btn">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="actions vertical">
        <li><a href="#" class="button special fit">Subscribe to Newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#menu .inner {
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.35s ease-out, opacity 0.35s ease, 
visibility 0.35s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s ease-out, opacity 0.35s ease, visibility 0.35s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.35s ease-out, opacity 0.35s ease, visibility 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s ease-out, opacity 0.35s ease, visibility 0.35s;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateX(20deg);
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 18em;
}

a#contact-btn {
    width: 18em;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu .inner>:first-child {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#menu .inner>:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

#menu ul.links {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul.links>li {
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul.links>li>a:not(.button),
#contact-btn {
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(212, 212, 255, 0.1);
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    line-height: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul.links>li>.button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

#menu ul.links>li:first-child>a:not(.button) {
    border-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: What CSS is creating this border?

Comment: i believe it's `#menu ul.links > li` or `#menu ul.links > li > a:not(.button), #contact-btn`

Comment: can you show the CSS?

Comment: just edited my post to show the CSS

Comment: Which pages are supposed to appear in your menu ? Can you show robots.txt code ?

Comment: isnt this a duplicate of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726078/how-do-i-exclude-rss-jekyll-feed-from-nav) where you asked how to exclude the robots.txt? You don't need to add a link to robots.txt as you don't want the user to go to it?

Comment: Home, About and Archive are the only pages in my menu. I don't know where the robots.txt code is coming from. robots.txt only outputs in HTML after jekyll builds or serves in `_site`folder. I thought there would be a way to remove the border somewhere in the liquid tag that's why I put up the code for it.